# How to enable users upload a file directly from my website to their GitHub repro?

Tags: github

I am looking for a way to enable users of my website to upload a file from my website to their GitHub repro. Is it possible?

I want them to be able to avoid the process of downloading and asking them to go to their GitHub project and upload it directly.